# Navigation in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement something that when the user clicks a button a the user will redirect to add page. I have tried this using `Navigate`. But I am getting this error. `Uncaught Error: <Navigate> may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.` Here is the code that I tried.

**Home.js**

```
const[gotoAdd, setAdd] = React.useState(false);

  if(gotoAdd){
    return <Navigate to="/Add"/>
  }

<Button color="inherit" onClick={()=>{
          setAdd(true);
        }}>Add Employee</Button>
```

**Add.js**

```
import React from 'react'

export const Add = () => {
  return (
    <div>Addd</div>
  )
}
export default Add;
```

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/en/6.4.5/hooks/use-navigate

Comment: The way you implemented `if()` logic is wrong here. we dont have to set state and then navigate to other routes, we have `useNavigate()` hook to do the job

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure that you must install react-router-dom and add it to your app

index.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  rootElement
)
```

in App component

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home/>} />
      <Route path='/abc' element={<Abc/>} />
      <Route path='/def' element={<Def/>} />
      <Route path='/xyz' element={<Xyz/>} />
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

After that, you will use useNavigate to navigate

useNavigate()

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Component() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  navigate("/add"); 
}
```

Comment: I dont have a app.js file I removed it